# media queries are working on local host but not on server

Tags: html, css, mobile, localhost, media-queries

I search a few other posts on this subject and still cant seem to get my media queries to work for mobile devices. I've added everything I can think of to my head and css but nothing seems to work.

Here is my code:

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user- 
scalable=yes">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon? 
family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<body>
```

css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
.material-icons{
font-size: 100%;
}
.header h1{
margin-top: 5px;
font-size: 150%;
}
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 750px) {
.material-icons{
font-size: 50%;
}
.header h1{
margin-top: 10px;
font-size: 80%;
}
.main-pic{
    height: 25%;
}
}

@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px){
.material-icons{
display: none;
}
.header h1{
margin-top: 10px;
font-size: 80%;
}

.main-pic{
    height: 25%;
}


}
```

Comment: you're declaring `<meta name="viewport">` in your `<head>` twice - remove the last one. Does that help?

Comment: I just updated the code and this does not seem to fix the issue

Comment: is your updated css uploaded correctly? ie what happens if you visit "yoursever.com/style.css" ?

Comment: The updated head now looks like this:

Comment: his the css is not updating correctly, what would i do in this case?

Comment: yes, i had to ctrl + f5 and the issue has been resolved, thank you

Comment: ctrl+f5 solved my problem too glad I read this comment

Comment: What does Ctrl + F5 do?